# Hyperplane which can separate two closed convex set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

Define:
$$E=:\ell^1(R)=\{x=(x_n)_n: \|x\|_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|<\infty\}$$
We have two closed convex sets $X,Y$ as subsets of normed vector space $\ell^1(R)$ with $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ and $Y$ is a subspace of $E$ and $$r=\inf_{x\in X , y\in Y}\|x-y\|_1$$ is positive(nonzero).

I wanted to define a hyperplane which can separate these two subsets and I found $a\in X, b\in Y$ such that $\frac{b+a}{2}\notin Y\cup X$ and for some positive $\varepsilon$ $$r\leq\|b-a\|_1<r+\varepsilon$$
I defined $f:E\rightarrow R$ by 
$$f(e)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e_n(b_n-a_n)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^2-b_n^2)$$
Now I need to prove that
$\Big[\text{for every  $x\in X$, $f(x)<0$ and every $y\in Y$, $f(y)>0$} \Big]$.

Comment: Hint: I have proved $f(b)>0,\ f(a)<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I checked it very well I understood it's not possible.Just define:

$$Z=\{(x_n)_n\in E: x_{2n}=0\}$$
and
$$Y=\{(y_n)_n\in E: y_{2n}=\frac{y_{2n-1}}{2^n}\}$$
and
$$c\in E :\ \ \ \  c_{2n}=\frac{1}{2^n}\ \ \ \ c_{2n-1}=0$$
and $X=Z-c$. Now use both $X,Y$ in the problem to reach contradiction.

For this construction check this book: "The Hahn-Banach Theorem" by "Haim Brezis".